# AngularJS conversion to Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to convert a simple little search app from a PHP end point to Firebase.

I have converted the controller over and it is working to display the data from firebase.

OLD PHP Endpoint

```
app.controller('InstantSearchController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('inc/api.php').success(function(itemData) {
        $scope.items = itemData;
    });
}]);
```

New Firebase Endpoint

```
app.controller('InstantSearchController', ['$scope', '$firebase', function($scope, $firebase) {
    var medRef = new Firebase("https://dazzling-fire-####.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.items = $firebase(medRef);
}]);
```

But I am not 100% sure how to swap the app.filter over to use the firebase data.

Here is what it was with the PHP End Point

```
app.filter('searchFor', function(){

  return function(arr, searchString){
    if(!searchString){
      return arr;
    }
    var result = [];
    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
      if(item.english.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
        result.push(item);
      }
      if(item.spain.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
        result.push(item);
      }
      if(item.germany.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
        result.push(item);
      }
      if(item.france.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
        result.push(item);
      }
      if(item.philippines.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
        result.push(item);
      }
      });
    return result;
  };

});
```

And this is what I was thinking "should" work but it doesn't, From doing some reading and watching of some tutorials i thought that i needed to switch item with id

```
app.filter('searchFor', function(){

  return function(arr, searchString){
    if(!searchString){
      return arr;
    }
    var result = [];
    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    return function(arr, searchString){
      if(!searchString){
        return arr;
      }
      var result = [];
      searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
      angular.forEach(arr, function(id){
        if(id.english.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
          result.push(item);
        }
        if(id.spain.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
          result.push(item);
        }
        if(id.germany.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
          result.push(item);
        }
        if(id.france.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
          result.push(item);
        }
        if(id.philippines.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
          result.push(item);
        }
        });
      return result;
    };
});
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great i am really trying to learn this AngularJS/Firebase stuff!

Comment: for starters in the second "searchFor" example, where does item come from? id is passed into function(id) in the previous example it was function(item). I can't imagine this even working even close to how you would expect. Can you put together a jsfiddle of it so I can see how it is currently built?